# Как поставить видео блок по гирине сайта?

Tags: html, css

На картинке видно как видео выходит за рамки мобильной версии сайта. Как сделать чтобы видео не выходило за рамко этого блока?

Спасибо.

Это на стринеце - https://mybibleverses.org/random-bible-verse/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас там не тег video а тег iframe в котором уже установлены ширина и высота - удалите их и стилизуйте через css

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.